# List is still passed by reference after using new List<T>(list)

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

In my controller I read the users from a CSV like this:

```
var users = Utilities.GetUsersFromCSV(path, userType, course);
```

This reads a CSV file and constructs `User` objects with it. One possibly relevant part is the creation of a password:

```
public static List<User> GetUsersFromCSV(string filepath, string userType, Course course) {
    var users = new List<User>();
    var user = new User();
    GeneratePassword(ref user);
    return users;
}

private static void GeneratePassword(ref User user) {
    var size = Rand.Value.Next(0, 3) + 8;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var shuffledlist = Chars.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          sb.Append((char) shuffledlist[i]);
    }

    user.Password = sb.ToString();
}
```

After the Users are created from the CSV file I want to add them to the database like this:

```
_userRepository.AddUsers(Utilities.HashPasswords(users));
```

Which calls

```
public static List<User> HashPasswords(List<User> users) {
   var newList = new List<User>(users);
   foreach (var user in newList) {
        user.Password = CalculateSha1Hash(user.Password, user.Login);
   }

   return newList;
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324790/are-ilists-passed-by-value) answer the user list that is being transmitted to the repository should now contain the hashed passwords, while the `users` list in my controller should still contain the original passwords. However during debugging I notice that `HashPasswords` also affects the passwords in `users`.

What is causing this?

Comment: This is correct as for a reference type a copy of the reference is passed to your method. But this reference still points to the same data. If you'd like to avoid this you have to create a copy of the object and pass this copy. This is stated in the link you've posted as well: 'If you want to make a copy of the list itself, List<T> has a handy constructor, that takes an IEnumerable<T>. '.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Method GetUsersFromCSV does not return a value.

Comment: @user1567896: Isn't that what `var newList = new List<User>(users);` does? @helb: obviously I've left out big parts of code, everything compiles. I'll edit it just to be clear.

Comment: I dont think the list is parsed by reference.. but the `Users` in the list might be!

Comment: @OP: It is as Rob already answered. You need to create a deep copy. (copy all intern values of your object to the 'new' object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `newList` object is a shallow copy. I would use a Linq `Select` on the original list to create a deep copy.

```
newList = users.Select(u => CopyAndChangePassword(u));
```